# Getting simple table to a word list with Kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I am trying to get a simple table for a strings (words) list using Kable in a Rstudio markdown. With MSword i get this example:[image: exampl]

I am trying to get this with Rstudio/Markdown in differents ways, but only get this:

```
    library(kableExtra)

    table= data.frame(words=c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco"))

    kable(table)

    table2= as.vector(table)

    kable(table2)

    table3=c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco")

    kable(table3)
```

**EDIT (I add another example) :**

@manro reply, work fine but not work for long list of string words.

```
  table_long= data.frame(words=c("uno", "hoy", "a", "al", "desconcierto", "nos", "estan", "por", "era", "otra", "con", "de", "hacia", "_"son", "h"sobre", "hasta", "quienes", "tratar", "nuestro", "y", "porque", "su", "eres" , "otro", "al", "mi", "aos", ".", "vueltas", "", "hacer"utilizando", "haciendo", "estimado", "realizando", "baja", "hago", "existen", "resto", "traves", "todas", "realice", "saber"posteriormente", "presentaron", "mandarlo", "veces", "ya", "posee", "b", "cosas", "hechos", "ud", "durante", "eran", "coste, "de", "o", "que", "todo","te", "ni", "tu", "antes", "pag", "bajo", "asi", "fue","una", "muy", "les", "ha sido", "desde", "puede", "a", rso", "sugiero", "oceanografia", "grabe", "ella", "casi", "fin", "da", "sr", "ahora","sido", "la", "a", "en", "y", "seguir", "nada"pues", "pudo", "profesor", "profesora", "punto", "profe", "temas", "unos", "dia", "gabriele", "a", "al", "de", "vuelven", "hizo", "de", "de", "que", "se", "y", "a", "un", "a", "al ", " al ", "ha", "no", "se", "los", "por", "al", "yo", "enviar", "usted", "cristian", s", "del",  "lo", "es", "para", "como", "direccion", "toda", "toco", "ser", "este", "pero", "donde", "el", "entre", "estos", "antes", "s, "ya", "o", "e", "mas", "dos", "han", "dirección", "decir", "le", "ex", "ante", "tras", "http", "noviembre", "borde", "segun", "quien", emas", "sobre", "esta", "dijo", "debe", "tengan", "parte", "tips", "tipo", "habia", "solo", "mil", "mucha", "mucho", "tener", "tiene", "si", "me", "ese", "eso", "hace", "hablaba", "ellos", "esto", "cuando", "esa", "va", "nos", "cada", "ahi", "tus", "uso", "dafne", "tanto", "vez", "año", "años", "tienen", "mayor", "hyperlink", "tenian", "tenia", "tan", "sea", "podria", "aunque", "mismo", "creo", "n", "tres", "ayer", "otros", "tambien", "https", "p", "nop", "dado", "alguna", "algunas", "estaba", "deberia", "cualquier", "hora", "poquito", "parecen", "grande", "hilo", "cerrar", "paso", "algo", "ocasion", "respecto", "sola", "segundo", "llegar", "parecer", "dice", "todos", "luego", "c", "fueron", "mientras", "pag", "alfo", "dentro", "alla", "cual", "caso", "dejado", "haces", "estar", "dan", "vaya", "pocos", "nuestra", "una", "hemos",  "estamos", "decia", "tuviera", "aveces", "tenido", "u", "vemos", "he", "aula", "mar", "topado", "sino", "cabo", "ac", "esas", "alfinal", "dante", "dan", "hofer", "juan", "deben", "estas", "ti", "quizas", "valio", "tenga", "siga", "pone", "via", "etc", "èl", "fui", "den", "ah", "ir", "tuve", "claudio", "has", "joaquim"))
```

[image: example2]

Comment: do you want to knit to word?

Comment: Not. I only want this kind of table. Not word.

Comment: @Rodrigo_BC In the HTML-file?

Comment: I need a pdf with a table like my first  example

Comment: @Rodrigo_BC Ok, I make it soon :)

Comment: @Rodrigo_BC look

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Lamentably dont work for long list of string words

Comment: I add another example with more string words

Comment: @RodrigoBadilla Look at the addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

````
   ```{r, echo = FALSE}
    
    library(kableExtra)
    library(data.table)
    
    table3 <- data.frame("uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco")
    
    table_t3 <- transpose(table3)
    colnames(table_t3) <- NULL
    
    kable(table_t3, format = "latex", align ="|c|", booktabs = T) %>%
        kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped", "hold_position")) 
    
    ```
````

[image]

---

**For the long list:**
add the `full_width = TRUE` to the `kable_styling`

```
kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped", "hold_position"), full_width = TRUE)
```

But borders don't work in this case.

[image]